# Prove these are not surface groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

For $g,n \geq 1$, let $\Gamma_{g,n}$ be the group with the following presentation:
$$\langle \text{$a_1,b_1,\ldots,a_g,b_g$ $|$ $[a_1,b_1]^n [a_2,b_2] \cdots [a_g,b_g]=1$} \rangle.$$
For $n = 1$, these are the fundamental groups of close genus $g$ surfaces.  I expect that they are not isomorphic to fundamental groups of closed surfaces for $n \geq 2$, but I can't figure out a proof (except for the trivial case $g=1$, where they have torsion).  Note that from the abelianization you can see that if they are surface groups they are also genus $g$ surface groups.  Can anyone prove this?

Comment: I think you can distinguish them from their 2-nilpotentizations (i.e. passing from $G$ to $G/[G,[G,G]]$). If $n$ has an odd prime divisor, the exponent $p$ quotient of the 2-nilpotentization should be enough, and otherwise, the exponent 4 quotient should be OK. There is a little work to fill in the details, and even more work if one wants to prove they are pairwise non-isomorphic when $n$ varies.

Comment: Another way to see that these groups are not surface groups is that they have cyclic JSJ decompositions with two quadratically hanging surface subgroups and one cyclic vertex group. Surfaces have the property that any two infinite cyclic splittings are mutually hyperbolic-hyperbolic with respect to a third, and these groups don't. I will not spoil the fun in the exercise.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an argument inspired by but not actually using one-relator group theory. Let's write $x_0$ instead of $a_1$ and $t$ instead of $b_1$ and then Tietze transform the presentation to
$$ \Gamma_{g, n} \cong \langle x_0, x_1, a_2, b_2, \dots, a_n, b_n, t \mid (x_0^{-1} x_1)^n [a_2, b_2] \dots [a_n, b_n] = 1, x_0^t = x_1 \rangle. $$
This expresses the group as an HNN extension over $\mathbb{Z}$. The base group however cannot be a subgroup of a surface group because its abelianization has torsion.

Comment: How do you see that the surface group cannot be expressed as HNN extension of a group with non-torsion-free abelianization ?

Comment: @YCor: Every subgroup of a surface group is either a surface group or a free group (and every infinite-index subgroup is a free group).

Comment: @AndyPutman ah indeed!

Comment: Perhaps it’s a good idea to clarify one implicit detail: the claim that the vertex group embeds follows from Britton’s lemma, which needs the hypothesis that $x_0$ and $x_1$ both have the same order. Fortunately, their images in the abelianisation show us that they both have infinite order!

Answer (score 7):

One can do this using group cohomology, specifically the symplectic form $H^1(G,\mathbb Z)\times H^1(G, \mathbb Z) \to H^2(G,\mathbb Z)$ arising from the cup product. I guess this is closely related to the two-step nilpotent completion [suggested by YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463427/prove-these-are-not-surface-groups#comment1203178_463427), the advantage is that the classification of symplectic forms is more transparent.

Given a group with one relation whose abelianization is trivial, there is a natural map $H^2(G, \mathbb Z) \to \mathbb Z$ which sends a central extension to the class of the relation (after lifting the generators, and this doesn't depend on the choice of a lift). It's not so hard to check this is an isomorphism.

I'll change your notation slightly so the generators are $a_1,\dots, a_{2g}$ and the relation is $[a_1,a_{g+1}]^n [a_2, a_{g+2}]\dots [a_g, a_{2g}]$.

$H^1(G,\mathbb Z)$ consists of linear forms on the abelianization, i.e. it is freely generated by $c_i$ that sends $a_i$ to $1$ and all other $a_j,a_j$ to $0$.

To calculate $c_i \vee c_j$, we just need to find the corresponding central extension and look at the image of the relation in it.  The central extension is pulled back from $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, where it is clearly the unique nontrivial central extension, i.e. the one with relations $[[a_i,a_j],a_i]$ and $[[a_i,a_j],a_j]$. The center is generated by $[a_i,a_j]$.

The image of $[a_1,a_{g+1}]^n [a_2, a_{g+2}]\dots [a_g, a_{2g}]$ is given by the sum for each appearence of $a_j$ of the number of copies of $a_i$ that appear before it minus the number of copies of $a_i^{-1}$ that appear before it. This gives a $2g\times 2g$ symplectic matrix which is a block sum of $g-1$ copies of the standard symplectic form plus one copy of $n$ times the standard symplectic form.

$n$ is an invariant of the isomorphism class of this symplectic form, as we can tell by putting it in Smith normal form (invariant under a coarser notion of isomorphism), which is a diagonal matrix with two $n$s followed by $2g-2$ ones.